# Flex how to differentiate between capital words, lower case words and words?

Tags: flex-lexer

I have the following rules:

```
capital_word    [A-Z]+
lower_case_word [a-z]+
word            [^ \t\n\.]
delim           [ \t\n\.]
```

For the word "Hello", it says "H" is a capital word and "ello" a lower case word. How could I do to have "Hello" as "Word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing a single word, you want to match the whole word, and you want to allow lowercase letters after the first capital.

```
capital_word    ^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+$
lower_case_word ^[a-z]+$
word            ^[^ \t\n\.]+$
delim           [ \t\n\.]
```

`^` is beginning of test and `$` is end of test, meaning you want to match all text. It's needed for the first three but not the last (since in last you just want to know if a delimiter is present, I think).